# Gradient Color on fonts in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

Can FreeType make gradient color like this?

[image]

If the answer is no, How can I achieve this on fonts in libGDX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve it is using [Hiero](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero) and it's gradient effect

[image]

You are generating two files with this:

- **.fnt** with font definition
- **.png** with font texture

You are using the generated font like

```
    BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont( Gdx.files.internal("font.fnt") );
```

Comment: Ya, I know it. But I not prefered to use it because when i want to scale font, it lose resolution. My comment is correct or wrong.??

Comment: Have you tried setting texturefilter? `BitmapFont font;
  font.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);`

Comment: Cool Cool. I will change all labels in my code to `BitmapFont` with `Hiero` :D.  but I want to answer me, WHY the `FreeType` extension exist as long as hiero make all those ??  WHAT are the advantages of each one ??

Comment: I tried to write your code `TextureFliter` and scalling, it's appear not cool. I changed the size font in hiero tool, then exported two images. So I checked the file size `*.ttf` and all files from hiero tool (.fnt and all images) not difference too much, it's fine.